# School Website Help: Template Element Extends Too Far Right

Tags: html, css, joomla, safari

Issue only relevant for Safari browser.

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here's a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of my problem]

As seen, the problem is with a bottom border extending too far right. This seems to be an issue with the original template. Yes, I've contacted the designer, but it appears they're of little help (even after purchasing the $10 "quick help").

Interestingly, when viewing the demo with their global site navigation, as seen [here](http://demo.themexpert.com/?theme=zenithii) the border is contained correctly, however, removing the top black navbar will produce the issue.

How can i fix this? Is there someway to implement the black navigation, but do so invisibly? Can I fix this with css? Please Advise?

Comment: Here are two more screenshots while inspecting the element. [One](http://i.imgur.com/RgpI08h.png) [Two](http://i.imgur.com/7b9pC2D.png)

Comment: You need to post the relevant coding or a link to your website.

Comment: apologies i wasn't very clear. the [template demo](http://demo.themexpert.com/?theme=zenithii) will display the issue after removing the top global (black) navigation, and my website can be found [here](http://www.vcomcc.com)

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot I can see you have `padding: 50px 100%` on your `.txtabs-content` div, the `100%` could be adding the unwanted padding, this should probably be `padding: 50px auto`.

Although, you should post some code and if possble, a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so this can be verified as the issue.

Comment: I tried setting the padding as described, however, that moved the text just below the "rogue" border slightly upwards while the border itself was unaffected. I'm not too savvy with most of this, so JSFiddle might be over my head. [Here's](http://vcomcc.com) a link to my site if that would help, and if I hear anything from the template authors I'll post back here, but I'm not holding my breath.